# How to do I do this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a set of data with fields SUBJECT, PRICE, ISBN and DATE. I want to return all results with the minimum PRICE where SUBJECT is "math" and ISBN is unique. If there the price is the same for a particular ISBN, I want the one with the earliest date.

```
SUBJECT PRICE ISBN DATE    
math    10    1    1-10    
math    20    2    1-11    
math    10    1    1-9
```

It would return math 20 2 1-11 and math 10 1 1-9.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `MIN()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
A.SUBJECT,
MIN(A.PRICE) PRICE,
A.ISBN,
(
    SELECT MIN(B.DATE) 
    FROM  your_table B 
    WHERE   B.SUBJECT = 'math' 
        AND B.ISBN = A.ISBN 
        AND B.PRICE = MIN(A.PRICE) 
) Date
FROM your_table A
WHERE SUBJECT = 'math'
GROUP BY  A.SUBJECT,A.ISBN
```

Comment: ...as an example of what not to do!

Comment: @mkRabbani why is it necessary to group by subject?

Comment: Your selected column either has to be part of GROUP BY or Aggregation. That's why GROUP by Subject is necessary.

Comment: Actually, the WHERE clause creates a functional dependency, rendering the GROUP BY on subject unnecessary. Nevertheless, it is good practice. But there remain profound problems with the above.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the earliest date also has the lowest price - the assumption in these answers is that the opposite is true - hence these answers will yield the wrong result.

Comment: @mkRabbani the date is actually a datetime in the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS." Is there any way to select the earliest datetime without casting a specific year using just min?

Comment: @Daniel That case no casting and other adjustment is required. Direct MIN will work. Edited.